# Simple code to make a table of numbers like this

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I need help with a simple program to print a table of numbers like this. It only has to work for when n is an odd number and not for even numbers. **like n = 3, 5, 7, 27**
I nearly finished it but can't figure it out to the end. A solution using for loop is preferred.
My code only works for table(5) but not for table(9) for example.

```
def table(n: int):
    for i in range(n // 2+1):
        for j in range(n):
            if j <= (n // 2):
                print(n-i-j, end="")
            else:
                print(j-i+1, end="")
        print()
    for x in range(n // 2):
        for y in range(n):
            if y <= (n // 2):
                print(n // 2 + x + 2 - y, end="")
            else:
                print(y // 2 + x + 2, end="")
        print()
```

How it is supposed to be:

```
5 4 3 4 5
4 3 2 3 4
3 2 1 2 3
4 3 2 3 4
5 4 3 4 5

table(9)
my output(wrong):
9 8 7 6 5 6 7 8 9
8 7 6 5 4 5 6 7 8
7 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 7
6 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 6
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
6 5 4 3 2 4 5 5 6
7 6 5 4 3 5 6 6 7
8 7 6 5 4 6 7 7 8
9 8 7 6 5 7 8 8 9
what it should be:
9 8 7 6 5 6 7 8 9
8 7 6 5 4 5 6 7 8
7 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 7
6 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 6
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
6 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 6
7 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 7
8 7 6 5 4 5 6 7 8
9 8 7 6 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: works fine for me when I put in `5` and `9`

Comment: It doesn't, bottom right side of the table(9) numbers are duplicated for a reason I cant figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def table(n: int):
    for i in range(n // 2+1):
        for j in range(n):
            if j <= (n // 2):
                print(n-i-j, end="")
            else:
                print(j-i+1, end="")
        print()
    for x in range(n // 2):
        for y in range(n):
            if y <= (n // 2):
                print(n // 2 + x + 2 - y, end="")
            else:
                # should be this instead of y//2
                print(x + 2 - n//2 + y, end="")
        print()
```

but actually you can do it in one line:

```
n = 9
[[1 + abs(i-n//2) + abs(j-n//2) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

[[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information?

Comment: I only changed one line which caused your duplicated number `y//2`